# Module not found when using flat-ui with webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, flatui

I want to use flat-ui with webpack when installed with npm.  I have created a [test project](https://gitlab.com/lifeofgary/tooling).  The last commit is before installing flat-ui.  When I do install and use

```
require('flat-ui');
```

I get the error:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'flat-ui'

In my research I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/victorouse/9f850adb162fc34ab254) but am not familiar enough with webpack to understand it well enough.

My goal is to use npm to install dependencies rather than clutter up my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'flat-ui' npm package is not official package. This package provides old version. ( [issue](https://github.com/kigawas/Flat-UI/pull/1) )

You need to install ['designmodo-flat-ui'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/designmodo-flat-ui) package.